# How to mouse hover a div, when another is hovered actually and vice versa

Tags: jquery, css

HTML CODE:

```
 <div class="item1">
   <div class="flip-container">
     <div class="flipper">
       <div class="front">rabbit imagw</div>
       <div class="back">apple image</div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
   <div class="flip-container">
     <div class="flipper">
       <div class="front">rabbit</div>
       <div class="back">apple</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.flip-container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.flip-container:hover .flipper,
.flip-container.hover .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front .name {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}
```

I am having more than ten item1 and item2 div's, in a grid layout. I need when item 1 is hovered, item 2 to be also have the hovered effect and vice versa. How to do this? I tried with JQuery, but due to lack of knowledge, I failed. Could someone help me out. Thankyou

Comment: @prakharlondhe it's not working with this solution

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work:

```
$('.item1').hover(function(e) {
    $('.item2').hover();
})
```

Comment: This code didnt work

Answer (score 0):

There should not be problem using this

```
$('.item1 .flip-container').on('mouseenter', function() {
  if($(this).is(':hover')) {
    $('.item2 .flip-container').trigger('mouseenter');
  }
});
```

The callback is triggered when the mouse enters the `.item1` element and the hover condition is just a double check before triggering the `.item2` forced state

Comment: Not working, should i do any changes in css.

Comment: Mmm, for the structure of your question I thought the items divs had the hover style... change the selector on the code to `.item1 .flip-container` and `.item2 .flip-container`